# Knife command works from one particular directory but not from others. why?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife, chefdk

I have created an organization called "kaushikinc" on chef server and have a directory structure "C:/x/y/z/kaushikinc".

When I execute a command from kaushikinc folder, they work fine but when I execute from a parent or child folder, they dont work. What am I doing wrong?

Ex: from a child folder: No success or error message:
[image]

But a success when I try from kaushikinc  folder[image]

Edit: Adding a new image to show that the problem exists even when I pass the location of knife.rb config file

[image]

Edit2: I run across this problem only when I use "--all" option on "knife data bag from file" command. I am able to execute any other command from any directory with -c enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is because the directory you're in, or a parent directory, contains a `.chef` directory. knife searches for `.chef` in:

- ./.chef (current directory contains .chef)
- ~/.chef (homedir contains .chef)
- parent directories (e.g. ./.. then ./../.. all the way back to /)

You can see [some of the logic itself here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/116e5219c717614658ecf2d7bf7f6b3420a8f6fe/chef-config/lib/chef-config/workstation_config_loader.rb#L47-L60).

Comment: I get your point. I have also tried using --config option along to provide .chef\knife.rb location. I have the same issue even after passing knife.rb location.

Comment: Edited my post. So If I give --config option, it shouldn't search for .chef directory right?

Comment: Yes, if you supply `-c <path_to_knife.rb>`, that will override everything else. I use this feature all the time.

Comment: But I still have the same problem even with -c. Check my last image in the question.

Comment: worth noting the `KNIFE_HOME` env variable can be set to the path containing the `knife.rb` file with the same effect as -c.

Comment: I need this command to be executed from a ruby code. So, changing KNIFE_HOME is not going to help much. My best bet is to use -c for flexibility. But do you think the issue is because of knife.rb? I do not understand how that is related. Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: What if you move all of your .chef directories to somewhere, and retry? I really do use the `-c` argument to knife in Linux probably 5-10 times a day. It's also possible it's a Windows bug with ruby/knife.

Comment: Okay. I guess I missed to clarify one more thing. I have this problem only when I use '--all' option for "knife data bag from file" command. Does that ring any bell?

Comment: @kaushikv I looked through the chef source, and I don't see anything specific to using `--all` that would change the behavior of specifying a configuration file with `-c`. Make sure `-c` is the last argument on the line?

Comment: @Martin.. Appreciate looking up chef docs for me. I have tried re-arranging the optons --all and -c and that doesn't seem to work. Moreover, you can see that -c is the last option in the last image posted in the question.